# Desgin ViewController with Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

I design the ViewController include 1 UIView and 1 button in it but when i deploy in the Emulatore, it 's not the same as what i see in storyboard file.

[image]

Comment: Uncheck autolayout and use size inspector

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of the auto layout constraints you have. The default screen size in the storyboard is for iPhone 5, but the default simulator is an iPhone 4 size, so by having fixed distance to both the top and bottom of the screen, the view has to be squished to satisfy the constraints.

To fix this, you should give the view a fixed height (from the menu, Editor --> Pin --> height), and then delete bottom constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use distance to superview to top, also set the virw height constant. You dont need the bottom constraint

Comment: This is what he already has (a constraint to the top and bottom), and this is what causing the problem.